# Express.js Node.js - OKTA getting user and groups info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, okta

I'm trying to get the user info by using `/users/:id` as well as the user's group info `/users/:id/groups` using OKTA API and the problem is that the response is sent as a string format and I need to `JSON.parse()` it before using, which obviously is an extra job. Did anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: To send as JSON, you could use `res.type('json')` before sending your actual response. That way, anything will be sent as JSON (any arbitrary string will also be sent as JSON, but will trigger an error at the client as it's not in valid format)

Comment: I think, this will work only if you are logged in with admin (okta admin) credentials. what about normal users ? (like we logged in with normal user and we want to know the group which this user belongs to ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was similar to the [Noob Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5283155/noob-coder)'s comment, I've used the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) middleware to make http requests, it gives you an request configuration option `{json : true}` which automatically

> sets body but to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.